# squared output photo similar to preview

Tags: android, commonsware-cwac

I have used the Commonsware-cwac library exactly like the demo app. After resizing the framelayout which the preview is contained in I achieve a squared preview that maintains correct ratio and preview size. However, after I capture I would like to get a a photo with the same size as the preview. Now, when I capture a new photo, the saved photo is much bigger due to the fact that it captures the original and non-squared preview.

How can the output photo capture the same as the preview and no more?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Option #1: You let the library save the image as it does today, then crop the image yourself

Option #2: You fork the library and add in some sort of cropping logic as part of `ImageCleanupTask`

Comment: Thanks, that helped me in the right direction. Btw, do you know how I can get the dimensions necessary for cropping to the correct size?

Comment: @Ole-M: Not really, as I do not know your implementation of anything. A maximally-sized square image would be a square who sides are as long as the shortest axis of the original image (e.g., the height for a landscape image). And, I would presume the default would be to crop equally on both sides of the long axis, thereby centering the square. But, again, that is merely one implementation of how to create a square subset of a rectangle.